# How to get CPU value for particular application

Tags: java, linux, performance, cpu, jmx

I have two application running in my VM, One is JAVA application and another one is nodejs application.
I have configured **JMX** for my **java application** and I observe the **CPU** information being collected, Is it whole system specific (or) amount of CPU consumed by my application?

**NOTE** : I observe 80% CPU in JMX so if it is application specific, does it mean that it is consuming 80% of the total CPU and remaining 20 percent is given to other applications?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Super quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends what exactly you are looking at.

The [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) allows you to query the **system load**. That means the overall CPU utilisation.

To measure the resources used by your JVM, have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html).

Comment: So does it mean that graph showing 80 percent CPU is total CPU?

Comment: @Harry If that is how you are measuring, I would say so. System load is system load. Alternatively, you could just run top or htop on the side, and see what this is telling you.

Comment: No I would like to understand JMX, it has heap and metaspace which I clearly know it's for my java application but not sure about the CPU graph shown there, is it application specific ? Or system specific?